# Output a list to a template in lift

Tags: lift

How can I output a list of things in a template in Lift?

Let say for example that I have **List[User]** and I want to output it as a table. In Django, I would use a context variable "users" and iterate through it in the template like so:

```
 //controller
 user = User.objects.all() 
 context = {'users' : users}
 return render_to_template('results.html', context}

 //view
 <table>
 {% for user in users %}
 <tr><td>{{user.name}}</td>
     <td>{{user.email}}</td>
 </tr>
 {% endfor %}
 </table>
```

I appreciate any help.

PS: Could you also show me an example of the scala side - as I am clueless about how to approach this problem.

Comment: This is SOO frustrating. I can't find the doc for this anywhere - and it is not intuitive at all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Template

```
<ul>
  <lift:UserSnippet.showAll> 
    <li><foo:userName />: <foo:age /></li> 
  </lift:UserSnippet.showAll> 
</ul>
```

Snippet Class

I'm assuming `users` is a `List[User]`.

```
import scala.xml.NodeSeq
import net.liftweb.util.Helpers

class UserSnippet { 
  def showAll(in: NodeSeq): NodeSeq = {
    users.flatMap { user => Helpers.bind("foo", in, "userName" -> user.name, "age" -> user.age) }
  }
}
```

See the lift wiki articles on [designer friendly templates](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Designer_Friendly_Templates) and [snippets](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Snippets) for more information.

Comment: What is the namespace for NodeSeq? I can't find it in the lift's api.

Comment: Also - you only show how to map one attribute - userName, what about "email"? Thanks!

Comment: I changed my answer to include import statements and to show how to display several attributes. If you can't find a class in the Lift API, it might be in the Scala API or it might even be a Java class.

Comment: what should I do to set i.e. href in <a> in each row of my table?

Answer (score 2):

if you're looking to use a pure java list, say an ArrayList from a seperate java call...you can do it this way....

Make sure to import the java conversions, and your java class file where your list is being created

(i'm assuming we have a list of "people" objects that is being returned from your java file, which would include a name, age, and sex properties)

```
//SCALA Code

import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import my.java.package.something._
import scala.xml.NodeSeq
import net.liftweb.util.Helpers

class mySnippet {

    //You want to run the ".toList" on your java list, this will convert it into a scala list
    val myScalaList = my.java.package.something.buildMyList().toList

    //This is the function that will bind the list to the html view
    def displayPeople(html : NodeSeq) : NodeSeq = {
      myScalaList.flatMap{person => bind("info", html, 
          "name", person.name,
          "age", person.age,
          "sex", person.sex)}
    }
}



//HTML code

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td>Sex</td>
        </tr>

       <lift:mySnippet.displayPeople>
            <tr>
                <td><info:name></info:name></td>
                <td><info:age></info:age></td>
                <td><info:sex></info:sex></td>
            </tr>
       </lift:mySnippet.displayPeople>
    </table>
```

Hope this helps  :)

-kevin