# Lift - Binding list of values to template

Tags: scala, lift

Here is my template -

```
      <div class="lift:Admin.showInvitees">
          <tr class="success"> <!-- "success" "error" -->
            <td><invitee:name></invitee:name></td>
            <td><invitee:description></invitee:description></td>
            <td><invitee:status></invitee:status></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
      </div>
```

and here is the snippet -

```
class Admin {  
  def showInvitees(in: NodeSeq): NodeSeq = {
    val invitees = Invitation.allInvitations
    invitees.flatMap{invitee => bind("invitee", in, "name" -> invitee.name.is, "status" -> invitee.status.is, "description" -> invitee.description.is)}
  }
}
```

I checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995078/output-a-list-to-a-template-in-lift) and used the solution. But it's not working for me. Values are not getting bound at all. This is what I get as output -

```
<tr class="success"> 
   <td><invitee:name></invitee:name></td>
   <td><invitee:description></invitee:description></td>
   <td><invitee:status></invitee:status></td>
</tr>
```

Need help binding a list of values to template.

After the first answer I tried this as well -

```
def showInvitees(in: NodeSeq): NodeSeq = {
val invitees = Invitation.allInvitations
(".invitees" #> invitees.map{ inv =>
    ".invitee-name" #> inv.name.is &
    ".invitee-description" #> inv.description.is &
    ".invitee-status" #> inv.status.is
})(in)
```

}

Even this is not working- 
Template -

```
<div class="lift:Admin.showInvitees">
      <tr class="invitees success"> <!-- "success" "error" -->
        <td><span class="invitee-name"></span></td>
        <td><span class="invitee-description"></span></td>
        <td><span class="invitee-status"></span> </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the old syntax for binding values. Try the new one:

```
// snippet
class Admin {  
  def showInvitees = {
    case class Invitee(name: String, descr: String, status: String)
    val invitees = List(Invitee("Alex", "for cookies", "ok"), Invitee("Bob", "for beer", "kicked out"))
    ".invitee" #> invitees.map { i =>
      ".invitee-name" #> i.name.is &
      ".invitee-descr" #> i.description.is &
      ".invitee-status" #> i.status.is
    }
  }
} 

// html
<div class="Admin.showInvitees">
  <table>
    <tr class="invitee success"> 
      <td><span class="invitee-name"></span></td>
      <td><span class="invitee-descr"></span></td>
      <td><span class="invitee-status"></span></td>
    </tr> 
  </table>
</div>

// result
  <table>
    <tbody><tr class="invitee success">
      <td>Alex</td>
      <td>for cookies</td>
      <td>ok</td>
    </tr><tr class="invitee success">
      <td>Bob</td>
      <td>for beer</td>
      <td>kicked out</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody></table>
```

Comment: It says type mismatch - required - scala.xml.NodeSeq but found net.liftweb.util.CssSel

Comment: @Shwetanka - Aah, sorry, I copied part of your example without looking :)

Comment: @Shwetanka - I updated the answer with the tested code. It seems that Lift's html parser didn't like the absence of "table" tag.